# How to include a formula with a data validation list

Tags: excel

guys. Excel newbie here. I have a data validation list containing three letters you can choose from a drop down list: A, B, C. These are 3 rankings depending on what is contained within the 2 cells left of it.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to have the drop-down list in the 3rd cell, while also having a formula that spits out "C" automatically if the 2 cells to the left down contain the same string.

for example:
B7 contains "no"
C7 contains "no"
D7 contains the drop-down list.

I would like for D7 to automatically display "C" if B7 is changed to "yes".

Thank you for any help you can provide.

I tried writing a formula in D7 for the desired outcome, but I get an error message. B7 and C7 also contain data validation lists which contain two options: "yes" or "no".

Comment: You can dynamically edit the given dropdown, but you can't automatically change the content of the cell. Assuming your a, b and c are stored in range A2:A4, use a validation list with the formula =IF(B7="yes",$A$4,$A$2:$A$4). Then again: you could actually change the content of the cell D7 via VBA.